# Custom Components IONIC 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, components

I have an ionic app and created a custom component for `ion-navbar` but, how could I use this component in all of my pages? If I declare him on all the pages i get this error

[image]

[image]

Here's my Github if u want https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/PManager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a shared module and include that new shared module as an import for the page modules that need the header:

shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header/header.component';
import {IonicModule} from '@ionic/angular';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule
    ],
    declarations: [HeaderComponent],
    exports: [HeaderComponent]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Then for the home.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),  
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Comment: Why do I need to wrap component in a module? Sometimes we just want to create component just for one page.

Comment: @Tukkan because the question is releated to all pages and not a single page.